# Python class that can be instantiated empty and with methods

Tags: python-3.x, class, methods

```
from movie import Movie


def run_tests():

    enter code here
    print("Test empty movie:")
    default_movie = Movie()
    print(default_movie)
    assert default_movie.title == ""
    assert default_movie.category == ""
    assert default_movie.year == 0
    assert not default_movie.is_watched

    initial_movie = Movie("Thor: Ragnarok", 2017, "Comedy", True)


run_tests()
```

Is it possible to create a class that can be instantiated like this?
I've came across and I don't know the solution to this.
The class needs to have an **init** and **str** constructors

This is what I came so far

```
class Movie:
    def __init__(self, title, year, category, is_watched):
        self.title = title
        self.year = year
        self.category = category
        self.is_watched = is_watched
    def __str__(self):
        return 'movie=> {} {} {} {} {}'.format(self.name, self.year, self.genre, self.is_watched)

#sw = Movie("SW", 1977, "action", 0);
#print(sw);
```

But when I run the test file regarding this class, a error is thrown

> TypeError: **init**() missing 4 required positional arguments:
>   'title', 'year', 'category', and 'is_watched'

Comment: Possible XY problem: why do you need to create a movie that doesn't have any details *about* that movie initially?

Comment: If there *is* a reason to create an empty movie, I would do so as an explicit special case, rather than as a default action. Define a class method that returns `Movie("", 0, "", False)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite simply yes:

```
 def __init__(self, title="", year=0, category="", is_watched=False):
```

May I kindly suggest you do the full official Python tutorial ? This would have answered your question...